# SQL condition with NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following working select:

```
SELECT
    TableA.FullName
FROM
    TableA,
    TableB
WHERE
    TableA.Contact = TableB.Contact
```

But I have some lines in TableB that have NULL in the `TableB.Contact` column, and I would like to show it. I tried:

```
WHERE
    (TableA.Contact = TableB.Contact OR TableB.Contact IS NULL)
```

Without lucky.

Comment: use the left outer join .... select * from tableA left outer join tableB on TableA.Contact = TableB.Contact where TableB.Contact is null

Comment: What would you like the row with tableB.contact equal to null to look like? All tableA.* fields set to null? Could you add some sample data and a desired result?

Comment: A `left join` doesn't solve the problem if the OP wants matching `NULL` values.

Comment: So if there are 3 records with `NULL` values in `TableB`, and 1 record in `TableA` that has a corresponding record in `TableB` what should be returned?

Comment: @AbeMiessler, should be returned 4 records. I want the matching and the nulls

Comment: What would be returned for `TableA` for the three null `TableB` records?  Can you post some sample data and the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN

```
    SELECT
        a.FullName, a.Contact, b.Contact
    FROM TableA a 
    LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.Contact = a.Contact
WHERE
    (a.Contact = b.Contact OR b.Contact IS NULL)
```

The WHERE clause is redundant here - is does the same as the LEFT JOIN

Comment: But I need to compare `TableA.Contact = TableB.Contact` because I using it to get another field.

Comment: You can add a where clause to this. You can use 'a' instead of 'TableA' - this is an alias. You can add this: WHERE
    (TableA.Contact = TableB.Contact OR TableB.Contact IS NULL) - but this is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an outdated JOIN format.  Try changing it to this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM 
TableA as a
LEFT JOIN TableB as b
ON a.contact = b.contact
```

Using a left join will pull all records from A regardless if there is a match in B.  This is a good explanation of how the various joins work:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Also, notice that I am specifically pulling only the columns I want instead of `*`.  This is a good habit to get into with SQL.

UPDATE:

After your comments, it seems like you are looking for a `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM TableA as a
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB as b
ON a.contact = b.contact
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `join` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA JOIN
     TableB
     ON TableA.Contact = TableB.Contact OR
        TableA.Contact IS NULL AND TableB.Contact IS NULL;
```

A `left outer join` won't do exactly what you want.  It keeps all rows in `TableA`, but doesn't check for matching values.

For performance reasons, the following might work better:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA JOIN
     TableB
     ON TableA.Contact = TableB.Contact
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM TableA CROSS JOIN
     TableB
WHERE TableA.Contact IS NULL AND TableB.Contact IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what he wants the output to be, but do you think this could be a case for a `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: @AbeMiessler . . . The OP says nothing about keeping non-matching rows in either table.  That is where an outer join would be used.  Of course, there is a bit of silence on what s/he really wants.  My first guess is that this is not an outer join.